# Is there a way around the strange behavior of a shadow catcher's projected shadows?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shadows, shadowcatcher

I'm working on some composites, where I need to mix 3D models with real photographs, and I need to use shadow catchers on both a ground plane, and on some rebuilt scene geometry to get accurate shadows, and to have those shadows on their own render pass in the compositor, but occasionally I'll end up with a scene where the shadow of one of the shadow catchers needs to be visible, and/or it's intersecting with one of the regular objects' shadows, and they sort of just end up canceling each other out, like in the photos. If anyone has any advice on this, I would really appreciate it. Thanks in advance!

Here is the example blend file, if it helps:
[image]

Here is the shadowing I would like.
[image: Shadow catcher ground, regular objects]
And this is the result using a shadow catcher ground plane, and a shadow catcher cylinder.
[image: Shadow catcher ground, shadow catcher cylinder, regular cube]

Comment: Yeah, this is a bit tricky since a shadow catcher is basically a holdout object, which is transparent and also makes everything transparent that's behind it. Somehow Blender calculates "double" shadows as holdout, or better, a shadow catcher doesn't receive shadows from other shadow catcher. Although this still doesn't explain why the shadow of the box disappears where the cylinder's shadow would be.

Comment: But to try to find a solution I would ask: what exactly are you trying to do? Do you need the shadow on the backside of the cylinder opposite the light, or the shadow of the cylinder on the box and the plane? Or both?

Comment: @vklidu I know you did something with shadow catchers quite a while ago... do you have a solution?

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Both. I mean the shadow on the backside of the cylinder isn't as important as the contact shadows/ambient occlusion between the cylinder and the cube, but I'm assuming those are a package deal anyway. I've tried turning off the cylinder's shadows, which gets rid of the cut-out part on the cube's shadow, but then I lose the ambient occlusion between the cube and the cylinder. I've also tried using holdout instead, which gets me the cylinder's shadow, but loses the whole shadow catch effect on the cylinder itself. Thanks for the response by the way!

Comment: If the shadow on the backside of the cylinder isn't that important (because I guess, if the cylinder is cut out to reveal something like a cylinder underneath it - doesn't that thing have shadows on the back?) why not simply set the cylinder to _Holdout_ instead of _Shadow Catcher_? Then it throws a shadow, doesn't make problems with the shadow catcher plane and still reveals the cylinder footage in the background.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann It's mostly because I need the contact shadows and subtle reflections that a shadow catcher would normally pick up from all of the surrounding areas. The shadows on the back would be present in the actual photo, but not the rim around the bottom of the cylinder, and the slight color reflections above that. For now, I've been using holdout when I need to the shadows visible, but it noticeably lowers the quality of the composite, and the volume of work is too high to do it manually, so I've been trying to figure out a workaround.